# ordered List index not updated correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an issue with the ngIf in Angular. So basically I want to implement a notification system to notify the user of what fields are missing.
Here is a stackblitz for the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behnqj
To reproduce:
1. first select the vehicle type 'plane', here everything is correct, the first error is removed and the second remains with index = 1.
2. Now refresh the stackblitz preview webpage and this time select the vehicle type 'car', we can now see that the first error is removed but the second remains with index = 2.

With some debugging I figgured out if I swap between conditions in the ngIf and do something like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedVehicleType === 'plane'; else carsOptions">
      <option *ngFor="let plane of planes; let i=index" [value]="plane" [selected]="plane === selectedVehicle" [hidden]="i===0"> {{plane}}</option>

    </ng-container>
  </select>

  <ng-template #carsOptions>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars; let i=index" [value]="car" [selected]="car === selectedVehicle" [hidden]="i===0" > {{car}}</option>
  </ng-template>
```

This will result to the same issue but this time with the issue occuring when we select 'plane' and not 'car'.

Comment: From testing, it seems like a race condition. If you wait 1ms before splicing the `errors` array it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

change it to this it will work :)

```
<div class="content">
        <span>errors:</span>
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li *ngFor="let error of errors; let i=index;"> {{(i+1)+ ". "+error}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

hope it helps.